# Does destroying a chest in a bastion remnant anger piglins?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing my first survival world in bedrock edition and am about to raid a bastion remnant. I'm trying to find the best way to loot the bastion without aggravating the piglins as much as possible. Will **destroying** the chests cause them to become hostile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if they see you, just the same as opening the chest.

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Piglin#Aggravation):

> Piglins are provoked by any player who:
>
> - Is not wearing any piece of gold armor.
> - Attacks a piglin or piglin brute, regardless if the player kills it in one hit or not.
> - **Opens or breaks a chest**, trapped chest, ender chest, shulker box, barrel, minecart with chest, or minecart with hopper.
> - Breaks a block of gold, gold ore, gilded blackstone, or nether gold ore.

Answer (score 0):

In the bastion remnants, the piglins are piglin brutes. They will attack you regardless of any armor (unless you are invisible) because they are purely hostile mobs.

Comment: Clarifying what I said: in the treasure rooms (which I’d assume is where you would open any chest) all the piglins are piglin brutes, which are purely hostile, making opening a chest obsolete.

Comment: Please edit your answer, it's free